# Is it possible to dynamically install packages for a "frozen" Python application?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I am currently working on a Python application. This project relies heavily on a plugin based framework, with most of the application's functionality coming from its extensive plugin library. This approach suits our application well because many users require a unique collection of functions and this allows them to install only the plugins they actually require. Each of our plugins defines a list of Python dependencies that are required for that plugin to work.

This works well when running the project in an IDE. If the user wants to install a new plugin, we download the plugin source code and `pip install` any plugin dependencies directly into the Python virtual environment that is being used to run the project.

Unfortunately, this same approach is not possible for the "frozen" executable version of our application. When we "freeze" our project using PyInstaller, all of the Python packages included in the virtual environment are bundled together with the project source code and the Python interpreter. So far I have been unable to find any way to include additional dependencies *after* the application has been frozen. I've managed to get the frozen application to install Python packages to an external "plugin_dependencies" directory when the user tries to install a new plugin; the problem I am having is figuring out how to get the application to recognize this directory and import the dynamically installed packages.

Is there any way to achieve this? I would prefer to continue using PyInstaller, but am open to considering alternative freezing tools if any of them more readily support the functionality I require. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps with https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html
You could check for packages in a particular location and import stuff from there with importlib

Comment: @NikolayHüttenberend, thank you for your suggestion. Please correct me if I am misunderstanding, but I believe we would need to change all of the import statements in all of our plugins to support this. Ideally, we would be able to link an external directory to the Python interpreter's import search path so that we can use the existing import statements. I understand that this may be wishful thinking and I will keep your solution in mind if I can't find a simpler fix.

Comment: Sure you'd need to change something, I guess that depends on how exactly you have implemented the plugins but I'd expect that you do not need to change anything in the plugins but rather just in the application that imports them. 

Another idea. If it is possible to install additional libraries in a pyinstaller packaged application, then you'd just need to monitor an external plugin directory for changes and then in a subprocess install any new plugins in the application environment; this way you won't need to change the imports.